# Show that a sequence converges(bounded and monotone decreasing)

Tags: calculus

Let $ \lbrace a_n\rbrace ^\infty_{n=1}  \subset R $ be a bounded sequence , $\forall k \in N, B_k = `\lbrace a_n | n>=k \rbrace` $ and define $\lbrace b_k\rbrace ^\infty_{n=1} = sup B_k $

Show that a sequence converges.

My Thoughts: I want to show that the sequence is bounded and monotone decreasing and as a result converges. Can someone help me formalize that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean a *sequence* rather than a *series*, I think. A series is the sum of a sequence of partial sums. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$$ is a series; $(a_n)$ is a sequence.

Comment: Are you trying to show $b_k$ converges, where $b_k=\sup\{a_n:\ 1\le n\le k\}$? If so, showing $b_k$ is bounded above and increasing is indeed the correct approach. Also, $\lim_{k\to\infty}b_k$ is often denoted $\lim\sup a_n$.